# Domain of wifi internet test

Tags: wi-fi, internet

My router has an adblocker, such that any request to a blacklisted domain is redirected to a port that returns a 1x1 pixel gif (pixelserv). At the moment, whenever my Galaxy S3 (with 4.3 Jelly Bean) connects to Wi-Fi, it asks me to sign-in, but my network requires no sign-in (via webpage redirect). I understand that when connecting, Android connects to a website or domain to ensure that it is not redirected, and that there is an internet connection. I think my adblocker is redirecting this request to the pixelserv, and the device therefore thinks that I must sign in to the network. I want to whitelist whatever IP or domain it is looking for. What is that domain or IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android sends a request to `http://clients3.google.com/generate_204`, and it expects a 204 response (the HTTP code for "no content").